# why am I not redirected after a ajax post?

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, post

I'm using a page (***file1.php***) to submit a specific number to another php file (***file2.php***) this second PHP file as to take data from a database and extract information then return it to ***file1.php***,
here is ***file2.php***

```php
<?php
require('../model/encapsulation.php');
require('../model/connection.php');
require('../model/bunchofmethod.php');
if (isset($_POST['SpecificNumber'])) {
    $NS = $_POST['SpecificNumber'];
    $info = execRequest::folderInfoFromNS($NS, $dbh);
    $name = $info['name'];
    $firstName = $info['firstName'];
    $UID = $info['UID'];
    $idFound = json_encode(array($name, $firstName, $UID));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <script src="../JS/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <?php
    if (isset($idFound)){
        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.post("../view/file1.php",
                {
                    idFound: <?php echo $idFound?>,
                    searchDone: 1
                });
        })
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</head>
</html>
```

when I submit a specific number with ***file1*** (it is only a regular form and a php part which vardump `$_POST['idFound']` if it is set) I'm redirected to ***file2*** but not redirected again to ***file1*** , why ?

Comment: Because you do not have a redirect in file 2.

Comment: I see no redirection code.

Comment: Actually, you don't need AJAX unless you prevent the redirect action of the post.

Comment: "take data from a database and extract information then return it to file1.php"  You would do this by creating a response in file2.php with the desired data, not by creating a new request to file1.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the process here.

If you want file1 to make a request to file2, and file2 to send a response, then it makes no sense to write code in file2 which makes an AJAX request to file1. You don't need a *new* request to file1 (because that creates a *new* call to a *new* instance of file1's script). What you need is simply for file2 to provide a *response* to the request coming from the original instance of file1.

So if you want file2 to respond and return the JSON data to file1, then simply echo it:

```
$idFound = json_encode(array($name, $firstName, $UID));
echo $idFound;
```

(And get rid of all the HTML and jQuery code).

The echoed data will then be returned as the response to file1's request.

Comment: and what should I do in file1 to request file2 ? I'm kinda lost now because at first I only wanted to do like if file to was like a form posting data to file1

Comment: well if you're wanting to return JSON from file2, then it probably makes most sense to do an AJAX call from file1 (e.g using jQuery's `$.get()`). That way you can talk to file2 without the user having to leave file1, or refresh the page. The JSON data will come back to file1 in the response, and you can use Javascript to process it, display it on the page, or whatever you want. Find a jQuery AJAX tutorial if you want some more examples.